# JavaScript table to shrink to fit its content

Tags: javascript, html-table

The following code produces cells with higher height that needed
I want cells to fit its inner canvas in order to draw a diagonal on them

```js
var miglobal = [];
var ref1 = document.createElement("table");
var refx = document.createElement("tbody");
ref1.appendChild(refx);
var ref2, ref3;

console.log(ref1);
for (var y = 0; y < 25; y++) {
    ref3 = refx.insertRow(y);

    for (var x = 0; x < 25; x++) {
        ref2 = ref3.insertCell(x);
        var cnv = document.createElement("canvas");
        cnv.setAttribute("id", ("mycnv" + (y * 25 + x)).toString());
        cnv.setAttribute("height", "30px");
        cnv.setAttribute("width", "30px");
        var cntx = cnv.getContext("2d");
        cntx.moveTo(0, 0);
        cntx.lineTo(30, 30);
        cntx.stroke();
        miglobal.push(cntx);
        ref2.appendChild(cnv);
    };
};
document.body.appendChild(ref1);
```

```css
table {
    border: 2px black solid;
}
tr:hover {
    background: red;
}
tr >td {
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 0;
}
td > canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

All is generated dynamically because 25*25 at hand table could be cumbersome

Comment: You are using CSS and position attributes to create the canvas size, remove the width and height CSS rules of canvas and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the canvas element is displayed as an inline element. This causes the generation of a line box with the canvas element by default aligned to the baseline of the line box. The extra space you are encountering is the space below the baseline (i.e. space for characters such as "g" that descend below the baseline).

In your example, you could change the canvas element to be displayed as a block element.  For example...

```
td > canvas {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

Or you could change the canvas element to be displayed with a different vertical alignment. For example...

```
td > canvas {
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```